# Changing the app config DB connection string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I programing C# project out of company network ,I connect this project to my home DB as details below:
Solution right click > add > add new item > C# items > Data > ADO.NET Entity Data Model > EF Designer from database

This action create below connection in app config file :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyHome-PC;initial catalog=TestC#;integrated security=True;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After I finish the project and tack a copy of my home DB and attach it to the work DB server , how change the connection string to my work DB server with below details ?

- Server name: `DB-SR`
- Authentication: SQL Server authentication
- Login: admin
- Password: 123456

Comment: Use a different build configuration and a config transform

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below, and it is working :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DB-SR;initial catalog=TestC#;user id=admin;password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```